# Is there some library in Java to compress Png images like pngout?

Tags: java, png-8

Is there some library in Java to compress Png images like pngout, pngcrush, optipng which are written in C/C++?

In continuation to what Phil has commented below, what I meant was reducing the file size of the image generated by the ImageIO class in Java by removing information that is not needed, same as what pngout does. When I ran pngout on the images that were generated by ImageIO class I was able to get about 50% reduction in file size (reduction size will vary based on images). So I wanted to know if there is any tool or library that could be interfaced with Java so that image files produced ImageIO class can have their size reduced.

Comment: A pure Java solution would be useful so it can be used in places like AppEngjne or Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call an executable from Java to do the work, or you could wrap the library using SWIG and call it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

[JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org) provides an object-oriented Java interface to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php).

> ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, and compose bitmap images. It can read, convert and write images in a variety of formats (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF. Use ImageMagick to translate, flip, mirror, rotate, scale, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves.